# How to use relative file paths in JSON-LD

Tags: schema, rdf, json-ld

I want to design a JSON-LD based schema for describing datasets. Similar to [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#format-data) data structure. However I can't use COCO for this applications, because reasons. I also can't always use URIs/IRIs for paths to assets, because data will be moving around internally (security/export controlled situation).

Imagine a folder like:

```
dataset
├── images
│   ├── 01.png
│   └── 02.png
└── index.json
```

Typically, `@id` would be a URI. Can I just use a relative path instead, like this example `index.json`?:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "ImageObject": "http://schema.org/ImageObject",
  },
  "@id": "no_idea_what_goes_here_usually_a_uri",
  "@type": "Dataset",
  "name": "My image dataset",
  "image_set": {
    "@type": "ImageDataset",
    "name": "My Cool Dataset",
    "files": [
      {
        "@id": "images/01.png",
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "name": "cat picture"
        ...
      },{
        "@id": "images/02.png",
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "name": "dog picture"
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or is there other chicanery I have to do with context/vocab to get this to work?  (I'm still a bit of a json-ld greenhorn) I mean, I could always just deviate from JSON-LD, but I'd like to stick with the spec as closely as possible and ideally leverage schema.org data structures wherever possible.

Edit 1: I'm going to be appending things as I go along fact-finding. It seems to further constrain my question, I think what I want is a jsonld file which, with the addition of some machine-specific context, can be expanded into a valid and fully qualified jsonld document. That probably means I want to inject or modify `@base`, `@context` and/or `@vocab`. Still not entirely sure which. [Here is an interesting related discussion](https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/issues/488).

[Sir Tim himself seems fine with the practicality and inevitability of relative URIs.](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Relative.html) Additionally, the [URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) does mention relative behavior as well. I mean, clearly, relative URIs are a thing, they are used all the time on the web. It's just not entirely clear the correct idioms to use in the context of JSON-LD's expansion engine.

Comment: `@base`? https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#base-iri

Comment: I *think* that is what I want? I might just need to sit down and read the URI RFC a few dozen times until it sinks in.

Comment: Although the question isn't related to JSON Schema (hence removing the tag), I can tell you that URI resolution is something people often struggle to understand. Eventually it's like riding a bike or driving a car. Keep at it.